# Array formula to lookup a string of comma separated values in a range and return every value in another comma separated string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a user-populated list of comma separated values (Next ID) to track links between some data. I need to look up every value in this cell and return every corresponding Name in another cell (Next Name). My output should look something like this:

| ID | Name | Next ID | Next Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID01 | Print | ID02,ID03 | Post,Scan |
| ID02 | Post | ID03 | Scan |
| ID03 | Scan | ID04,ID05 | Process,Bill |
| ID04 | Process |  |  |

I have managed to create a macro to do this, but I am wondering if this could also be achieved with an array. This would make it easier to distribute the table via the web etc.

I've tried using a combination of Textjoin, Search, Vlookup and even FilterXML to try and achieve a working array formula but the only semi-working formula I have seems to just return the first name in the list:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE([@[Next ID]],",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),Tbl_Processes[[ID]:[Name]],2,0))`

Achieves:

| ID | Name | Next ID | Next Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID01 | Print | ID02,ID03 | Post |
| ID02 | Post | ID03 | Scan |
| ID03 | Scan | ID04,ID05 | Process |
| ID04 | Process |  |  |

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this without using a macro?

Comment: Have you tried to hit the `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode? If no then do it please it needed because you may not be using `MS365`

Comment: This has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73380515/performing-a-lookup-for-delimited-values-in-a-single-cell-and-concat-results) before. It also includes the FILTERXML in case you don't have the `TEXTSPLIT` yet in your version. (I have no tested if that one works, the textsplit (as shown below here as well) does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per tags, then you could try using the following formula

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(C2,","),A$2:A$5,B$2:B$5,""))
```

---

You can also use one single dynamic array formula to spill the output like as below,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=MAP(C2:C4,LAMBDA(α,TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(α,","),A$2:A$5,B$2:B$5,""))))
```

---

Note that the last output is not showing as in expected of your post since there is no `ID05` in the source data, once you add it would show the desired result as well.

---

However, it seems like you are using **`Structured References`** aka `Tables`, and if you are not using MS365 then the formula needs to be committed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while when you do that in `Tables` it will return one output and not the array returned value within <kbd>TEXTJOIN()</kbd> function.

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
   FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE([@[Next ID]],",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),Tbl_Processes,2,0),""))
```

---

Like wise Dynamic Spill array formula also don't work with `Tables` there you can use the first approach as shown again here below using `Structured References`

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT([@[Next ID]],","),Tbl_Processes[ID],Tbl_Processes[Name],""))
```

---

Comment: This works great with the structured references still in place

Comment: Glad to know that it worked =)

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup Delimited String (`FILTER/SEARCH`)

[image]

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", , FILTER([Name], ISNUMBER(TOCOL(SEARCH(TOROW([ID]), [@[Next ID]]))), ""))
```