# Vlookup equivalent for dropdown list with two or more inputs, in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

---

[image]

I have a lookup tab where I specified a region for each country of expertise (never mind the title of the column).

I have a data input tab with a dropdown where you can select more than one country. If there is one country selected, then there is a Vlookup that picks the corresponding region.

I would like to create a formula so that if more than one country is selected, then the corresponding regions appear, comma separated. So for the choice of "Algeria, Armenia, Barbados" I would like the output to be: "South Med, Caucasus, Caribbean".

If two countries of the same region are selected, then show the region only once.
E.g. if the user selects Armenia, Azerbaijan from the multiple selection dropdown, then show only Caucasus in the region.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of doing this, also it seems like you are using `Structured References` aka `Tables` then the following formula should work provided you change the name of the tables accordingly with accordance to the following formula, using `TEXTJOIN()` and `IF()` with `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", ",,1)=Expertisetbl[Country],Expertisetbl[Region],""))
```

---

Or, Use the following if applicable to your version of Excel:

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(Expertisetbl[Region],1-ISNA(XMATCH(Expertisetbl[Country],TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", "))),""))
```

---

Formulas will automatically filled down due to the `Structured References` as well as makesure to change the `Table` names as per your suit.

---

Here is reference of other ways posted earlier: [Array formula to lookup a string of comma separated values in a range and return every value in another comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77149271/8162520)

---

Comment: @InesGuardans `TEXTSPLIT()` is applied on cell `D2` which is `Regiontbl` Table while the `Expertisetbl` is the `Table` range starts from `A1:B29` as per the given screenshot

Comment: This code works great! Can we edit it so that if the region is already included then it's not included twice? For instance both Algeria and Tunisia are South med, so if it's already there once then it's not duplicated. Thank you!

Comment: Try wrapping within `UNIQUE()` function: `=ARRAYTOTEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Expertisetbl[Region],1-ISNA(XMATCH(Expertisetbl[Country],TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", "))),"")))`

Comment: And the first one needs an additional function `TOCOL()` since its 2x2 --> `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", ",,1)=Expertisetbl[Country],Expertisetbl[Region],NA()),2)))`

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", ",,1)=Expertisetbl[Country],Expertisetbl[Region],""))
This is the one that worked, do i add unique() here?

Comment: See my previous comments and commenting again: like this way: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", ",,1)=Expertisetbl[Country],Expertisetbl[Region],NA()),2)))`

Comment: Amazing! thank you! and what's the reason for adding NA() which wasn't in the original code?

Comment: `NA()` returns `#N/A` error so wrapping that whole `IF()` logic within `TOCOL()` to make it into a single col array as well remove the errors

Comment: Or you can simply do this as well: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(TEXTSPLIT([@Country],", ",,1)=Expertisetbl[Country],Expertisetbl[Region],""))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this one by dragging down.

=TEXTJOIN(",",,VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(E6,","),$B$2:$C$27,2,0))
```

[image: Result]